# need help with this exercise please (java absolute beginner)

Tags: java

```
public class Format {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s1 = "ICS";
    String s2 = "Computing";
    String s3 = "PE";
    String s4 = "Sport";
    String s5 = "ENGL";
    String s6 = "Language";

    // Print above strings in a tabular format

    }  
}
```

Complete above Java program such that it prints these strings exactly as shown in the following table, having each entry starting precisely at the same column of the one in the previous row:

```
First Name    Last Name
=======================
ICS           Computing
PE            Sport
ENGL          Language
```

NOTE: Your program should work for any set of strings, NOT ONLY the given ones in the exercise.

Comment: The point of homework is for you to do it yourself

Comment: Homework! It's far too simple for SO :)

Comment: The point of homework is that you can learn from it. What have you tried already? What do you need help with?

Comment: When asking for help with your homework here, please show what you have done so far and explain _exactly_ what you are having issues with. You have not done this - you simply reposted your homework not showing us _any_ effort.

Comment: this is an excercise not homework

Comment: "I hear and I forget.  I see an I remember.  I do and I understand" - Confucius

Comment: Ask google about  "String formatting in Java"

Comment: @mohammad: what have you tried so far? Do you have a clue how to begin?

Comment: Exercise, homework, assignment all mean the same!

Comment: @ Lekensteyn the problem is I don't understand the question really well. if someone reexplain to me the question and I may able to start. I solved lots of questions (hard) so far but this I don't understand it so I don't know what is going on with it.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, then you should correct your question in "I don't understand the question in this exercise". :-)

Comment: @Lekensteyn you're correct. I was just so frustrated that I'm stucked at this.

Answer (score 3):

You must format String appropriate

This can help you:

```
String s1 = "ICS";
String s2 = "Computing";
...
String format = "%1$-14s%2$-9s\n";
System.out.format(format, "First Name", "Last Name");
System.out.println("=======================");
System.out.format(format, s1, s2);
System.out.format(format, s3, s4);
System.out.format(format, s5, s6);
```

then output is exactly what you need. But if you need some dynamic version you need just count "14" and "9" in your way.

If you want learn how you can format String look at [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0463.html) tutorial. It contains similar formatting and help you in the future with similar exercises

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is work out the size required for the first column. This is the maximum of the four values:

- 10, the size of "First Name".
- the size of `s1`.
- the size of `s3`.
- the size of `s5`.

That can be calculated with the current pseudo-code:

```
c1len = length ("First Name")
if length (s1) > c1len:
    c1len = length (s1)
if length (s3) > c1len:
    c1len = length (s3)
if length (s5) > c1len:
    c1len = length (s5)
```

Once you have that, it's a simple matter of formatting the relevant strings based on that length.

This is basically:

```
output "First Name" formatted to length c1len
output "  Last Name" followed by newline
for i = 1 to c1len:
    output "="
output "===========" followed by newline.

output s1 formatted to length c1len
output "  "
output s2 followed by newline

output s3 formatted to length c1len
output "  "
output s4 followed by newline

output s5 formatted to length c1len
output "  "
output s6 followed by newline
```

You should look into the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class, specifically `length()` and `format()`, `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`.

Comment: Thanks but I can't solve it with IF statement because we still in the beginningof the course

Comment: If you can't use the `if` statement, it's going to be difficult to meet your "should work for any set of strings" requirement. Certainly not without some even _more_ complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at System.out.println()

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Format {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    String s1 = "ICS";
    String s2 = "Computing";
    String s3 = "PE";
    String s4 = "Sport";
    String s5 = "ENGL";
    String s6 = "Language";
    String sep= "          ";



    // Print above strings in a tabular format
    System.out.println(s1 + sep.substring(s1.length()) + s2);
    System.out.println(s3 + sep.substring(s3.length()) + s4);
    System.out.println(s5 + sep.substring(s5.length()) + s6);


    }
}
```